# Need to install openjdk-6-jre-headless, but the Debian package won't install. What should I do?

Tags: debian, installation, java, debian-lenny

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I have Debian Lenny and am trying to install openjdk-6-jre-headless

Also, I do have plenty of RAM available, but the installation keeps on failing.

sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre-headless

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libhtml-template-perl mysql-server-5.0
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  openjdk-6-jre-lib
Suggested packages:
  libnss-mdns sun-java6-fonts
Recommended packages:
  ca-certificates-java
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  openjdk-6-jre-headless openjdk-6-jre-lib
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
Need to get 28.8MB of archives.
After this operation, 79.7MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Get:1 http://security.debian.org lenny/updates/main openjdk-6-jre-lib 6b11-9.1+lenny2 [5271kB]
Get:2 http://security.debian.org lenny/updates/main openjdk-6-jre-headless 6b11-9.1+lenny2 [23.6MB]
Fetched 28.8MB in 4s (6194kB/s)                   
Selecting previously deselected package openjdk-6-jre-lib.
(Reading database ... 24343 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking openjdk-6-jre-lib (from .../openjdk-6-jre-lib_6b11-9.1+lenny2_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package openjdk-6-jre-headless.
Unpacking openjdk-6-jre-headless (from .../openjdk-6-jre-headless_6b11-9.1+lenny2_i386.deb) ...
Setting up openjdk-6-jre-lib (6b11-9.1+lenny2) ...
Setting up openjdk-6-jre-headless (6b11-9.1+lenny2) ...
*** glibc detected *** /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin/java: free(): invalid pointer: 0xb7639274 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/libc.so.6[0xb7ec0845]
/lib/libc.so.6(cfree+0x9c)[0xb7ec26ec]
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/i386/client/libjvm.so[0xb79cfab1]
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/i386/client/libjvm.so[0xb798fe3b]
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/i386/client/libjvm.so[0xb7991740]
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/i386/client/libjvm.so[0xb7995ce6]
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/i386/client/libjvm.so(JNI_CreateJavaVM+0x69)[0xb781c699]
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin/java(JavaMain+0x9e)[0x804a36e]
/lib/libpthread.so.0[0xb7fa1f3b]
/lib/libc.so.6(clone+0x5e)[0xb7f20bee]
======= Memory map: ========
08048000-08050000 r-xp 00000000 fe:02 7831580                            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java
08050000-08051000 rw-p 00008000 fe:02 7831580                            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java
08051000-08072000 rw-p 08051000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
95300000-95321000 rw-p 95300000 00:00 0 
95321000-95400000 ---p 95321000 00:00 0 
954cf000-954db000 r-xp 00000000 fe:02 6285821                            /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
954db000-954dc000 rw-p 0000b000 fe:02 6285821                            /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
954dc000-b54dc000 rwxp 954dc000 00:00 0 
b54dc000-b54dd000 rwxp b54dc000 00:00 0 
b54dd000-b555c000 rwxp b54dd000 00:00 0 
b555c000-b5584000 rwxp b555c000 00:00 0 
b5584000-b755c000 rwxp b5584000 00:00 0 
b755c000-b7563000 r-xp 00000000 fe:02 7825080                            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/i386/libzip.so
b7563000-b7564000 rw-p 00006000 fe:02 7825080                            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/i386/libzip.so
b7564000-b7588000 r-xp 00000000 fe:02 7825070                            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/i386/libjava.so
b7588000-b758a000 rw-p 00023000 fe:02 7825070                            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/i386/libjava.so
b758a000-b7596000 r-xp 00000000 fe:02 7825086                            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/i386/libverify.so
b7596000-b7597000 rw-p 0000c000 fe:02 7825086                            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/i386/libverify.so
b7597000-b759f000 rw-s 00000000 fe:02 7831614                            (deleted) /tmp/hsperfdata_root/680
b759f000-b75a8000 r-xp 00000000 fe:02 6287813                            /lib/libnss_files-2.7.so
b75a8000-b75aa000 rw-p 00008000 fe:02 6287813                            /lib/libnss_files-2.7.so
b75aa000-b75b2000 r-xp 00000000 fe:02 6287802                            /lib/libnss_nis-2.7.so
b75b2000-b75b4000 rw-p 00007000 fe:02 6287802                            /lib/libnss_nis-2.7.so
b75b4000-b75bb000 r-xp 00000000 fe:02 6287806                            /lib/libnss_compat-2.7.so
b75bb000-b75bd000 rw-p 00006000 fe:02 6287806                            /lib/libnss_compat-2.7.so
b75bd000-b75d0000 r-xp 00000000 fe:02 6287803                            /lib/libnsl-2.7.so
b75d0000-b75d2000 rw-p 00012000 fe:02 6287803                            /lib/libnsl-2.7.so
b75d2000-b75d4000 rw-p b75d2000 00:00 0 
b75d9000-b75e0000 r-xp 00000000 fe:02 7825067                            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/i386/native_threads/libhpi.so
b75e0000-b75e1000 rw-p 00006000 fe:02 7825067                            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/i386/native_threads/libhpi.so
b75e1000-b75e8000 r-xp 00000000 fe:02 6287811                            /lib/librt-2.7.so
b75e8000-b75ea000 rw-p 00006000 fe:02 6287811                            /lib/librt-2.7.so
b75ea000-b75ed000 ---p b75ea000 00:00 0 
b75ed000-b763a000 rwxp b75ed000 00:00 0 
b763a000-b765e000 r-xp 00000000 fe:02 6287793                            /lib/libm-2.7.so
b765e000-b7660000 rw-p 00023000 fe:02 6287793                            /lib/libm-2.7.so
b7660000-b7a18000 r-xp 00000000 fe:02 7825079                            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/i386/client/libjvm.so
b7a18000-b7a37000 rw-p 003b8000 fe:02 7825079                            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/i386/client/libjvm.so
b7a37000-b7e56000 rw-p b7a37000 00:00 0 
b7e56000-b7f8e000 r-xp 00000000 fe:02 6287808                            /lib/libc-2.7.so
b7f8e000-b7f8f000 r--p 00138000 fe:02 6287808                            /lib/libc-2.7.so
b7f8f000-b7f91000 rw-p 00139000 fe:02 6287808                            /lib/libc-2.7.so
b7f91000-b7f94000 rw-p b7f91000 00:00 0 
b7f94000-b7f96000 r-xp 00000000 fe:02 6287805                            /lib/libdl-2.7.so
b7f96000-b7f98000 rw-p 00001000 fe:02 6287805                            /lib/libdl-2.7.so
b7f98000-b7f9b000 r-xp 00000000 fe:02 7825053                            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/i386/jli/libjli.so
b7f9b000-b7f9c000 rw-p 00003000 fe:02 7825053                            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/i386/jli/libjli.so
b7f9c000-b7fb0000 r-xp 00000000 fe:02 6287801                            /lib/libpthread-2.7.so
b7fb0000-b7fb2000 rw-p 00013000 fe:02 6287801                            /lib/libpthread-2.7.so
b7fb2000-b7fb5000 rw-p b7fb2000 00:00 0 
b7fb5000-b7fc9000 r-xp 00000000 fe:02 6286645                            /usr/lib/libz.so.1.2.3.3
b7fc9000-b7fca000 rw-p 00013000 fe:02 6286645                            /usr/lib/libz.so.1.2.3.3
b7fcd000-b7fce000 rw-p b7fcd000 00:00 0 
b7fce000-b7fcf000 r--p b7fce000 00:00 0 
b7fcf000-b7fd1000 rw-p b7fcf000 00:00 0 
b7fd1000-b7feb000 r-xp 00000000 fe:02 6287796                            /lib/ld-2.7.so
b7feb000-b7fed000 rw-p 0001a000 fe:02 6287796                            /lib/ld-2.7.so
bffc6000-bffd9000 rwxp 7ffffffea000 00:00 0                              [stack]
bffd9000-bffdb000 rw-p 7fffffffd000 00:00 0 
bfffe000-c0000000 r-xp bfffe000 00:00 0                                  [vdso]
/var/lib/dpkg/info/openjdk-6-jre-headless.postinst: line 73:   680 Aborted                 $basedir/bin/java -client -Xshare:dump -Xmx256m -XX:PermSize=128m > $log
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
dpkg: error processing openjdk-6-jre-headless (--configure):
 subprocess post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openjdk-6-jre-headless
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks a lot like [Debian bug 517084](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=517084).

So you'll probably have to wait until that gets fixed. If the Debian devs can't help you, it's relatively unlikely someone here will be able to.